# JHipster 7.7.0 monolith app with mssql failed to start, throws SSL exception

Tags: sql-server, jhipster

I generate a monolith app with jhipster 7.7.0, and dev database with mssql. start mssql with docker compose file, app failed to start and throws exceptions below

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 驱动程序无法通过使用安全套接字层(SSL)加密与 SQL Server 建立安全连接。错误:“PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target”。 ClientConnectionId:8fccc405-3626-4feb-bf8c-57119f629fe5
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3680)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:2113)
......

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
......

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
......

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
```

Comment: i noticed jhipster 7.7.0 upgrade mssql-jdbc driver to 10.2.0, after change datasource url to `url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=demo;encrypt=false` or `url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=demo;;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true`, the app successfully started

Comment: It's documented that [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server 10.2 changes to `encrypt=true` by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver#94). The same change of default applies to [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0 and later](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-general-availability-of-microsoft-data-sqlclient-4-0/ba-p/2983346).